# Gradle, test.single system property is not used with suiteXMLBuilder closure specified

Tags: gradle, testng

My use case is rather simple. I would like to run a single test from the command line of a Gradle project. Additionally, there is a TestNG suite which contains the test organization (either in XML or generated via the suiteXMLBuilder).

The behavior I'm seeing is the 'test.single' property is ignored if a suite is specified via: (1) suiteXMLBuilder, or (2) when an explicit suite xml is used.

This feature is [documented in the user guide (section 23.12.2)](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), so this would appear to be a bug. Its feasible to create a task which dynamically generates another suite xml for a single class, but this seems a bit overkill for this simple usage.

Has anyone come across similar behavior? Any information is welcome.